# Jersey Web Service sends 415 status code

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, http-status-codes, jersey-1.0

I have created a webservice using jersey for my Jave EE web application created using servlets.I find that I get a `415 error code`.

I usually either redirect to another `servlet` or to a  `jsp` which is technically a servlet in my app.Which `mime-type` should I use?

```
  SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,   and Java type interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
   The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
   application/octet-stream ->
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
   */* ->
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

This is the `network` tab in Google Chrome:

```
 Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8180
 Request URL:http://localhost:8180/GoogleMapsLoadingTest/MainService?   
 scenario=c&operation=1&objkey=000001&objtype=EQUI&gisuniqkey=fsfsfsfs2436353535
 Request Method:GET
 Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
 Request Headersview source
 Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
 Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,en-AU;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,te;q=0.2
 Cache-Control:max-age=0
 Connection:keep-alive
 Cookie:JSESSIONID=6ECE1D6B441026B523FA64E66F869C55
 DNT:1
 Host:localhost:8180
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     
 Chrome/34.0.1847.132 Safari/537.36
 Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
 scenario:c
 operation:1
 objkey:000001
 objtype:EQUI
 gisuniqkey:fsfsfsfs2436353535
 Response Headersview source
 Content-Length:0
 Date:Sat, 26 Apr 2014 10:48:33 GMT
 Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

## UPDATE:

Removed all the annotations for the code and added the servlets to the `web.xml` file:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet /GoogleMapsLoadingTest threw load() exception
    com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
at  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5320)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Is it even advisable to use my servlet package as the one with the web-service?

Comment: Show us the REST method responsible for the request (the one annotated with `@PATH` or `@GET` / `@POST` ...). It seems you didn't annotate correctly or forgot to annotate some of its parameters.

Comment: @AndreiI can I annotate a servlet with `@Path` and other such stuff

Comment: a Rest Class should be a simple POJO (not a servlet). Servlets are a different API (used by the JAX-RS implementations). Please ask my question above.

Comment: @AndreiI I was confused,so I built it both ways,[this is the POJO representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356678/containerexception-when-trying-to-build-web-service)

Answer (score 8):

Add @Context attribute to the **HttpServletRequest** parameter of your service method